# Removing everything after # in href in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have links in side the class li class `pivot-nav-item` that have `href=#sometext`. I would like to remove everything after the # if s certain condition is met. I am using the following code to see if the user has touched the screen to add a class `user-is-touching`. Therefore I would like to remove everything after the # if the user has touched the screen.

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function onFirstTouch() {
// we could use a class
document.body.classList.add('user-is-touching');

// or set some global variable
window.USER_IS_TOUCHING = true;

// or set your app's state however you normally would

// Remove mouse-related events here

 $(".o-c, .c-f, .i-c, .c-u").unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave')

// we only need to know once that a human touched the screen, so we can stop 
listening now
window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch, false);
}, false);
```

```js
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function onFirstTouch() {
  // we could use a class
  document.body.classList.add('user-is-touching');

  // or set some global variable
  window.USER_IS_TOUCHING = true;

  // or set your app's state however you normally would

  // Remove mouse-related events here

  $(".o-c, .c-f, .i-c, .c-u").unbind('mouseenter').unbind('mouseleave')

  // we only need to know once that a human touched the screen, so we can stop listening now
  window.removeEventListener('touchstart', onFirstTouch, false);
}, false);



$(".o-c").click(function() {
  if ($('body').hasClass('user-is-touching')) {




  } else { //do something else


  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>



  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-attr="o-c" class="o-c default-underline" href="#o-c" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">O C</a></li>
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-attr="c-f" class="c-f" href="#contact-form" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">C F</a></li>
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-attr="i-c" class="i-c" href="#i-c" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">I C</a></li>
</body>
```

Comment: is it just one `#` or do you have multiple ?

Comment: I have multiple li  with clas `pivot-nav-item` that have one #

Comment: Wh dont you use `a.split('#')[0]`

Comment: inside the touchstart function or click function?

Comment: is your condition suppose to make the href as `#` ?

Comment: @user38208 click function i guess, but totally upto to you as you want to use it

Comment: @NidhinJoseph Yes if user-is-touching make href ='#contact-form' inside pivot-nav-item to  href ='#' for example

Comment: @harshitverma how would i target just pivot-nav-item?

Comment: so then why not  do something like `$('.pivot-nav-item a').attr('href', '#')`

Comment: @NidhinJoseph I added it in the click function but doesnt seem to remove the text after the #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `attr()` to set the `href` attribute of the link.

```js
$('.pivot-nav-item').on('click', function() {
  $(this).find('a').attr('href', '#');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul>

  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-attr="o-c" class="o-c default-underline" href="#o-c" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">O C</a></li>
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-attr="c-f" class="c-f" href="#contact-form" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">C F</a></li>
  <li class="pivot-nav-item"><a data-attr="i-c" class="i-c" href="#i-c" data-toggle="my-scrollspy-2">I C</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I am trying to add the following : 
$(".o-c").click(function() {
    if ($('body').hasClass('user-is-touching')) {
   $(".o-c").find('a').attr('href', '#'); but doen;t seem to work

Comment: in this case, your code is `$(".o-c").attr('href', '#');` let me know if it works